# How to get the class of VfNetCallback<T>

Tags: java, reflection

```
public abstract class VfNetCallback<T> extends AbsCallback<VfNetResponse<T>> {

  @Override
  public VfNetResponse<T> parseNetworkResponse(Response response, int id) throws Exception {
    VfNetResponse<T> netResponse = JSON.parseObject(response.body().toString(), VfNetResponse<T>.class);
    return netResponse;
  }
}
```

I can use

```
Class<T> dataClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

to get the class of `T`. But how can I get the class of `VfNetResponse<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i found a solution.

```
@Override
public VfNetResponse<T> parseNetworkResponse(Response response, int id) throws Exception {
    Type dataType =  ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    Type type = new ParameterizedTypeImpl(new Type[]{dataType}, null, VfNetResponse.class);
    VfNetResponse<T> netResponse = JSON.parseObject(response.body().string(), type);
    return netResponse;
}
```